# pandas.Series.from_array has Deprecated since version 0.23.0 , how to replace from_array in new version?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I use this code :
 `freq_series = pd.Series.from_array(frequencies)`

and I get this error :

> AttributeError: type object 'Series' has no attribute 'from_array'

how can I replace `pd.Series.from_array` in new version ?

All of my code :

```
def Analiz_groups(frequencies,x_labels):
    # Bring some raw data.
    # In my original code I create a series and run on that,
    # so for consistency I create a series from the list.
    freq_series = pd.Series.from_array(frequencies)
    # Plot the figure.
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    ax = freq_series.plot(kind='bar')
    ax.set_title('Group Points')
    ax.set_xlabel('Title')
    ax.set_ylabel('Points')
    ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)
    # Call the function above. All the magic happens there.
    add_value_labels(ax)
    plt.savefig("image.jpg")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only `Series` constructor:

```
freq_series = pd.Series(frequencies)
```